# KSH Split String Issues

Tags: ksh

I have a string in a variable Var.
And the value looks like this:

`Var="Key1:Val1~Key2:Val2~"`

I just simply need this split by "~" and assigned to an array in KSH only

When I try `Var2=$(echo $Var | sed $'s/~/\\n/g')`

and check the size of Var2 array as follows:
`ArrSize=${#Var2[@]}`

I always get 1. I would have imagined that would be 2. Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to use the `x=( list of array items )` method of populating the array then you need to wrap the right side of the assignment in a pair of parens, eg:

```
$ Var2=( $( echo $Var | sed $'s/~/\\n/g' ) )

$ typeset -p Var2
typeset -a Var2=(Key1:Val1 Key2:Val2)

$ echo "${#Var2[@]}"
2
```

Other options that accomplish the same thing but reduce the overhead of subprocess calls:

*here string*:

```
$ Var2=( $(sed 's/~/ /g' <<< "${Var}") )

$ typeset -p Var2
typeset -a Var2=(Key1:Val1 Key2:Val2)

$ echo "${#Var2[@]}"
2
```

*parameter substitution*:

```
$ Var2=( ${Var//\~/ } )

$ typeset -p Var2
typeset -a Var2=(Key1:Val1 Key2:Val2)

$ echo "${#Var2[@]}"
2
```

**NOTE:** while `${var//~/ }` works in `ksh`, other shells (eg, `bash`) require the `~` to be escaped (ie, `\~`); `ksh` appears to work with both - `~` and `\~` = so I've updated the answer to include the escape

Comment: I needed a backslash in `echo "${Var//\~/ }"`. Do you know why?

Comment: @WalterA what shell are you in? question is tagged `ksh` so I was just focusing on that, ie, `ksh93` replaces the `~`; looks like `bash` requires the `~` to be escaped ... so I'm guessing `~` is a special character in `bash` though to be honest I'm just guessing at this point; also looks like escaping the `~` also works so a (somewhat) portable answer would include the escape; I'll update the answer ...

Comment: I was in bash indeed.

Comment: @Markp-fuso - I really appreciate the suggestion/solution. I will try this out and keep everyone posted. Thanks again. Upvoted your solution (for now, until I try it out and mark it as answer)